# Skip rows in source sheet when dragging down formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, row, drag

I am trying to drag down a formula that is pulling data from one sheet into another. I need to skip rows on the sheet that it is pulling from.

Example:

```
='Heat 1'!AG2
='Heat 1'!AG6
='Heat 1'!AG10
```

etc.

I did some research and found a few formulas that I thought might work, but they were looking to have the formula skip rows on the sheet that is pulling, not that is getting pulled from.

Comment: Can you please share a sample spreadsheet with your sample data and expected output so that the community can further visualize what you meant by skipping rows?

Comment: @PatrickdC Here is a link to the sample sheet [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nv3cVzr7RQyNydhBOyAzXz9WhWk2g14JHInGF8kHXcM/edit?usp=sharing. I am trying to get the "All" sheet to match the averages that are on the "Heat [1] [2] & [3]" sheets without having to connect them individually. Each one should be 4 rows apart from the other.

Comment: The file is not publicly shared. It cannot be viewed by the community.

Comment: It should be good now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out which allows you to get the whole output table in one go:*

```js
=let(Λ,reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(G:G,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,map(indirect(c&"!A2:A"),lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,{Σ,torow(offset(Σ,,column(AG1)-1,4))})))))),
     filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)))
```

- *the tab names needs to be listed in `Column_G` (**as in screenshot**). You could hardcode them within the formula too if thats how you need it...*

[image]

Comment: That worked with the numbers. I had put numbers "1, 2, 3, etc." in place of names for privacy reasons. If I were to have names in the A column, what would the change be? I added random names to the sample sheet.

Comment: then this part of the formula `index(Λ,,1)` would be `index(Λ,,1)<>""`